# Trying to get property 'column_name' of non-object while displaying data on view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to show data on my blade view from relationship data but when am trying to display data whereas table contains only one row of data it's showing on view but if I insert more than one data in table it's giving me an error.

I have three tables `courses`, `sections`, `course_section`. In `course_section` table these are the following columns `course_id` and `section_id`.

I have tried `{{ $section->courses()->first()->courseTitle }}` this snippet in view found on stackoverflow.

My Section Model code:-

```php
class section extends Model
{
  public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\admin\course\course','course_sections','course_id');
  }
}
```

My Section Controller code:-

```php
$sections = section::with('courses')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
      return view('backend.courses.section.all',compact('sections','courses'));
```

My view code:-

```html
@foreach ($sections as $section)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $section->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $section->courses()->first()->courseTitle }}</td>
          </tr>
@endforeach
```

I am getting this error

> "Trying to get property 'courseTitle' of non-object (View:
>   resources/views/backend/courses/section/all.blade.php)"

Comment: you should do another foreach for the relationship.

Comment: I want to display data in table and one-course name at a time https://i.ibb.co/WchY7gQ/section.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the following you are doing wrong:

1. Replace `$section->courses()` with `$section->courses` as you are already doing early loading. And `$section->courses()` will query to db again.
2. Check if relational data exists then show.

So your code would be as follow:

```
@foreach ($sections as $section)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $section->title }}</td>
    <td>
        @php
           $course = $section->courses->first();
        @endphp

        {{ $course->courseTitle or "" }}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Let me know if it helps!

**Edited:**

As per conversation the relationship has been changed like `course ->hasMany -> sections` and `section ->belongsTo -> course` so the blade would be change like.

```
@foreach ($sections as $section)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $section->title }}</td>
    <td>
        @php
           $course = $section->course;
        @endphp

        {{ $course->courseTitle or "" }}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195306/discussion-on-answer-by-vikash-pathak-trying-to-get-property-column-name-of-no).

Answer (score 2):

Section Controller:

```
$sections = section::with('courses')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
return view('backend.courses.section.all', compact('sections'));
```

In the View you have to loop the sections and then the courses and create each row. For ex:

```
@foreach ($sections as $section)
    @foreach ($section->courses as $course)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $section->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $course->courseTitle }}</td>
          </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note it's $section->courses and not $section->courses(), because the related courses are already there, you doesn't need to query them again.

---

**Update**

Or you can do the query over `course`

```
$courses = course::with('sections')->get();
return view('backend.courses.section.all',compact('courses'));
```

And in the View:

```
@foreach ($courses as $course)
    @foreach ($course->sections as $section)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $section->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $course->courseTitle }}</td>
          </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @porloserros I used your solution but it's repeating the first row from the table only.

Comment: all the courses have the same courseTitle? maybe you should do the query about the model course with its related sections

Comment: @AbhishekNimbalkar I updated the answer with another option. I do not know if I'm understanding what you want to achieve